# Getting an Oauth 2.0 API signed request to work in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get a signed Oauth 2.0 to work in python to feed a Django app.
Here is the closest that I got, using this code:

```
from oauth_hook import OAuthHook
import requests
import json

OAuthHook.consumer_key = "key"
OAuthHook.consumer_secret = "secret"
oauth_hook = OAuthHook("access_token", "", header_auth=True)

client = requests.session(hooks={'pre_request': oauth_hook})
response = client.get('https://demo.checkfront.com/api/2/booking/form/')
results = json.loads(response.content)

print response.content
```

But all I got is this:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Malformed auth header"}
```

Consider that from the API provider I got:

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Authorize Token URL
- AccessToken Url
- Access Token
- Refresh Token

The process works in PHP, this is the code

```
<?php

include('../lib/CheckfrontAPI.php');

class Checkfront extends CheckfrontAPI {

    public $tmp_file = '.checkfront_oauth';

    public function __construct($data) {
        parent::__construct($data);
        session_start();
    }


    final protected function store($data=array()) {
        $tmp_file = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $this->tmp_file;
        if(count($data)  ) {
            file_put_contents($tmp_file,json_encode($data,true));
        } elseif(is_file($tmp_file)) {
            $data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents($tmp_file)),true);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function session($session_id,$data=array()) {
        $_SESSION['checkfront']['session_id'] = $session_id;
    }
}


$Checkfront = new Checkfront(
    array(
        'host'=>'MY_ACCOUNT.checkfront.com', 
        'consumer_key'  => 'consumer_key',  
        'consumer_secret' => 'consumer_secret',  
        'redirect_uri'=>'oob', 
        'refresh_token' => 'refresh_token',  
    )
);


if($data = $Checkfront->cql('select * from status')) {
    print_r($data);

} elseif($Checkfront->error) {
    //
    print "Error: \n" . var_export($Checkfront->error,true);
}
?>
```

and this is the CheckfrontAPI.php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkfront SDK 
 * PHP 5 
 *
 * @package     CheckfrontAPI
 * @author      Checkfront <code@checkfront.com>
 * @copyright   2008-2012 Checkfront Inc 
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php New BSD License
 * @link        http://www.checkfront.com/developers/api/
 * @link        https://github.com/Checkfront/PHP-SDK
 *
 *
 */


/*
 * @access public
 * @package Checkfront
*/
abstract class CheckfrontAPI {

    protected $sdk_version = '1.1';
    protected $api_version = '2';

    public $error = array();
    private $api_timeout = '30';

    private $host = "";
    public $consumer_key = "";
    private $consumer_secret= "";
    private $access_token = '';
    private $refresh_token = '';

    private $server_token = ''; // legacy 

    private $api_id = 'UA';

    private $session_id = '';

    abstract protected function store($data);
    abstract public function session($session_id,$data);

    function __construct($config=array(),$session_id='') {
        $this->host = $config['host'];
        $this->consumer_key = $config['consumer_key'];
        $this->consumer_secret = $config['consumer_secret'];
        $this->redirect_uri = $config['redirect_uri'];
        $this->oauth_url = "https://{$this->host}/oauth";
        $this->api_url = "https://{$this->host}/api/{$this->api_version}";
        $this->app_id = $config['app_id'];
        $this->client_ip = $config['client_ip'];
        $this->refresh_token = $config['refresh_token'];
        $this->session_id = $session_id;
        $this->account_id = $config['account_id'];
        $this->server_token = $config['server_token'];
        $this->tokens();
    }

    /**
     * Check and refresh access token if needed.
     *
     * @return bool 
     */
    private function init() {
        if(isset($this->refresh_token)) {
            if(!$this->access_token or $this->expire_token < time()) {
                $this->refresh_token();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * API call via curl
     *
     * @param string $url 
     * @param array $data post / get data
     *
     * @return array json parsed response array
     */
    final private function call($url,$data=array(),$type='') {


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Checkfront PHP/SDK {$this->sdk_version} ({$this->app_id})");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        // set custom headers
        $headers = array('Accept: application/json');

        // legacy
        if($this->server_token) {
            $headers[] = "X-Server-Token: {$this->server_token}";
        }

        if($this->client_ip) {
            $headers[] = "X-Forwarded-For: {$this->client_ip}";
        } else {
            $headers[] = "X-Forwarded-For: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
        }

        if($this->account_id) {
            $headers[] = "X-On-Behalf: {$this->account_id}";
        }

        if($this->access_token) {
            $headers[] = "Authorization: BEARER {$this->access_token}";
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // pass session id
        // @see session_create()
        if($this->session_id) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "session_id={$this->session_id}");
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->api_timeout);

        if($data) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            if(is_array($data)) {
                // needs to encode to support assocative arrays
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            } else {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }
        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        }


        if($response = curl_exec($ch)) {
            curl_close($ch);
            $response = json_decode($response,true);
            if($response['error']) {
                $this->error = array('id'=>$response['error'],'msg'=>$response['error_description']);
                return false;
            } else {
                return $response;
            }

        } else {
            $this->error = array('curl'=>curl_error($ch));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the session
     *
     * @param string session_id
     * @param array $data session
     *
     * @return bool
    */
    final public function set_session($session_id,$data=array()) {
        $this->session_id = $session_id;
        return $this->session($session_id,$data);
    }

    /**
     * API request
     *
     * @param string $url 
     * @param array $data post / get data
     *
     * @return array json parsed response array
     */
    final function api($path,$data=array()) {

        $this->init();

        $url .= $this->api_url . '/' . $path;
        if($response = $this->call($url,$data)) {
            if($response['session_id']) {
                $this->session($response['session_id']);
            }
            return $response;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Authorize request
     *
     * @param bool $redirect automatically send the redirect header
     *
     * @return mixed Returns if $redirect is true returns bool, otherwise returns the authorization URL
     * @link http://www.checkfront.com/developers/api/#oauth
     */
    final public function authorize($redirect=1) {
        $args = array(
            'type'=>'web_server',
            'client_id'=>$this->consumer_key,
            'redirect_uri'=>$this->oauth_redirect_uri,
            'response_type'=>'code',
        );
        $url = $this->oauth_url . '/?' . http_build_query($args);

        if($redirect) {
            return header("Location: {$url}");
        } else {
            return $url;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Fetch access token
     * @param string $code returned from Checkfront::authorize()
     * @return mixed 
     */
    final public function fetch_token($code) {

        $data = array(
            'type'=>'web_server',
            'client_id'=>$this->consumer_key,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_secret' => $this->consumer_secret,
            'redirect_uri'=>$this->redirect_uri,
            'code'=>$code,
        );


        $url = $this->oauth_url . '/token/';
        if($tokens = $this->call($url,$data)) {
            if($tokens['error']) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $this->tokens($tokens);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Refresh access token
     * @param string $code returned from Checkfront::authorize()
     * @return mixed 
     */
    final private function refresh_token() {

        $data = array(
            'type'=>'web_server',
            'client_id'=>$this->consumer_key,
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'client_secret' => $this->consumer_secret,
            'redirect_uri'=>$this->redirect_uri,
            'refresh_token'=>$this->refresh_token,
        );

        $url = $this->oauth_url . '/token/';
        if($tokens = $this->call($url,$data)) {

            if($tokens['error']) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $this->tokens($tokens);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Get expire token datetime
     *
     * @param integer $time seconds to expore
     *
     * @return integer unix date - expire dirft. 
     */
    private function expire_token($time) {
        return time() + $time - $this->expire_drift;
    }


    /**
     * Set access token  
     *
     * @param array $data Token data (access_token,refresh_token,expire_token)
     *
     * @return mixed 
     */
    private function tokens($data=array()) {

        if($data) {
            if($data['expires_in']) {
                $data['expire_token'] = $this->expire_token($data['expire_in']);
            }
            $this->store(
                array(
                    'refresh_token'=>$data['refresh_token'],
                    'access_token'=>$data['access_token'],
                    'expire_token'=>$data['expire_token'],
                    'updated'=>time()
                )
            );
        } else {
            $data = $this->store();
        }

        if(isset($data['access_token'])) $this->access_token  = $data['access_token'];
        if(isset($data['refresh_token'])) $this->refresh_token = $data['refresh_token'];
        if(isset($data['expire_token'])) $this->expire_token = $data['expire_token'];
    }


    /**
     * CQL Query
     * @param sting $q SQL style query 
     * @return mixed sql results, or false on failure
     * @link http://www.checkfront.com/developers/api-cql/
     */
    final public function cql($q) {
        $this->init();
        if($data = $this->get('cql',array('q'=>$q))) {
            return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * API GET request
     *
     * @param string $url 
     * @param array $ags get data
     *
     * @return array json parsed response array
     */
    final public function get($path, $data=array()) {
        if($data) $path .= '/?'  . http_build_query($data);
        if($response = $this->api($path)) {
            return $response;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * API PUT request
     *
     * @param string $url 
     * @param array $ags put data
     *
     * @return array json parsed response array
     */
    final public function put($path,$data) {
        return $this->api($path,$data,'put');
    }


    /**
     * API DELETE request
     *
     * @param string $url 
     *
     * @return array json parsed response array
     */
    final public function delete($path,$data) {
        return $this->api($path,$data,'delete');
    }


    /**
     * API POST
     *
     * @param string $path uri path
     * @param array $data post data
     *
     * @return mixed 
     */
    final public function post($path,$data) {
        return $this->api($path,$data);
    }


    public function session_clear() {
        $this->session_id = 0; 
    }
}
?>
```

How can I get this API calls signed with Oauth 2.0 to work under python/django?

Answer (score 0):

The Checkfront API is OAuth2, and requires use of a bearer token as per the OAuth2 (reviosn 20).

I haven't worked with the Django oauth library, but I'd check to make sure that it supports OAuth2.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm crazy late to this party, but I just recently committed both a simple OAuth 2.0 client ([sanction](https://github.com/demianbrecht/sanction)) and a Django front end for it ([django-sanction](https://github.com/demianbrecht/django-sanction)). I'm assuming that it's far too late for the OP, but perhaps it'll help others who stumble on this question.